# Python Protocol error: Incompatible types in "yield" (actual type "Type[Foo]", expected type "FooProtocol")

Tags: python, pytest, protocols, python-typing

Lets say I have a class "Foo" and class "Database". "Database" class provides connection engine, sessions and other related db stuff. Foo class intantiates this class (and some other attributes). "Foo" acts like some context class for entire application, but that does not matter for this question.

```
from some_module import Database

class Foo:
   bar: str = "some string"
   database: Database = Database("target_database_url")
```

If I create a protocol class that should represent the type of Foo class:

```
class FooType(Protocol):
   bar: str
   database: Database
```

And somewhere later in my code I have a pytest fixture. Basically I can not add Foo in  "-> Generator[Foo,None,None]" because Foo needs to be imported (does not matter why) inside the fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=False, scope="session")
def foo_fixture() -> Generator[FooType,None,None]:
    #I can not import this at the top, but this is not the issue for this question.
    
    from some_other_module import Foo  
    yield Foo
```

```
I get this error: Only class variables allowed for class object access on protocols, database is an instance variable of "Foo"
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: you're yielding the class, not an instance

Comment: Don't you mean classvars, like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=91a7f37fa6a5646b9522e7e1244e443f) (passes)?

Comment: @joel yes, it is a class, and "bar" and "database"  are class variables. I can access it easily. "Database" is an instantiated object. Typical class variables, I just don't get why are they interpreted as instance variables??

Answer (score 0):

From [pep 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#protocol-members):

> To distinguish between protocol class variables and protocol instance variables, the special ClassVar annotation should be used as specified by PEP 526. By default, protocol variables as defined above are considered readable and writable.

So you can fix your code to make it pass the mypy check with

```py
class Foo:
   bar: ClassVar[str] = "some string"
   database: ClassVar[Database] = Database("target_database_url")
```

However, I'm fairly sure that this is not *exactly* what you want because, as mentioned in the comments, you yield the class `Foo`, while the return type expects an instance of `FooType`.
In this case, it all matches because if we treat `Foo` as an object (classes are objects too, after all), then it has the "instance variables" `bar` and `database`.

A more intuitive solution would be to

1. yield a `Foo` object, or
2. change the return type of `foo_fixture` to `Generator[Type[FooType], None, None]` (or the simpler `Iterator[Type[FooType]]`). In this case, you could, optionally, change the variable types to `ClassVar[...]` in both `Foo` and `FooType`.